# Get Job Details from PushGateway Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

`PushGateway` doesn't expose any `GET` operation to retrieve Job details stored in it. Can this be considered as an option? I'd guess it can be used in conjunction to already exposed operations like `DELETE` using the job details for stale data clearance?? Any insight please? How else can the stale data in PushGateway can be cleared w/o manual intervention?

Answer (score 0):

The only time there would be stale data in the pushgateway is when you decommission a job, in which case doing it manually via the UI is fine (and the only interface offered)

You should probably read https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/ as I think you may be using the pushgateway for something it's not intended for.

Comment: I completely agree. Prometheus is being used as a central monitoring system in an architecture where apps are deployed in Cloud, CloudFoundry. As of now we don't see any Eureka (Service-Registry) integration for Prometheus, so hosting Prom inside CF doesn't help much. Sitting outside CF, the only possible option to use Prometheus seems to be PushGateway. Since it's not ideal for monitoring apps that are real-time sync in nature, we are looking for work-around(s) where data can be published to Pushgateway and idle/stale data can be cleared.

Comment: You can use file_sd to get targets from Eureka: https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus/

Comment: Thanks Brian. But there is no guarantee the eureka node info will be static. It can also vary.